# OpenMP with 1 thread slower than sequential version

Tags: c, performance, openmp

I have implemented knapsack using OpenMP (gcc version 4.6.3)

```
#define MAX(x,y)   ((x)>(y) ? (x) : (y))
#define table(i,j)    table[(i)*(C+1)+(j)]

   for(i=1; i<=N; ++i) {
#pragma omp parallel for
      for(j=1; j<=C; ++j) {
         if(weights[i]>j) {
            table(i,j) = table(i-1,j);
         }else {
            table(i,j) = MAX(profits[i]+table(i-1,j-weights[i]), table(i-1,j));
         }
      }
   }
```

execution time for the sequential program = 1s

execution time for the openmp with 1 thread = 1.7s (overhead = 40%)

Used the same compiler optimization flags (-O3) in the both cases.

Can someone explain the reason behind this behavior.

Thanks.

Comment: Might very well be OpenMP overhead. Actually parallel code can never be faster than sequential code when using a single processor. BTW are you sure that your measurings are correct and significant to what you try to do?

Comment: 1s is actually a long time so my first guess is the overhead would be insignificant.  What compiler options you used.  Did you tell the compiler to optimize the code (e.g. with -O3, -O2, or -Ofast)?

Comment: I even tried for runtimes of 15s still I can see 3s of overhead.
I was using -O3 for both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enabling OpenMP inhibits certain compiler optimisations, e.g. it could prevent loops from being vectorised or shared variables from being kept in registers. Therefore OpenMP-enabled code is usually slower than the serial and one has to utilise the available parallelism to offset this.

That being said, your code contains a parallel region nested inside the outer loop. This means that the overhead of entering and exiting the parallel region is multiplied *N* times. This only makes sense if *N* is relatively small and *C* is significantly larger (like orders of magnitude larger) than *N*, therefore the work being done inside the region greatly outweighs the OpenMP overhead.

Comment: Exactly, that's my thoughts as well.  Assuming N is larger enough then the overhead should be insignificant.  I would also be surprised if compiler optimizations made so much of a difference (1s vs 1.7s).  That's why I'm wondering if optimization was even used and if it was it would be interesting to compare the assembly output with and without OpenMP.

Comment: @Zboson, `i` is a shared variable in the parallel region. GCC converts any instance of `i` in the region into `omp_arg->i` where `omp_arg` is a structure that contains copies of all shared variables in the region and a pointer to it gets passed as an argument to the function that implements the region. When compiled as serial, `i` is most likely kept in a register the whole time. Therefore making `i` `firstprivate` should improve the performance to a certain extent.

Comment: Oh, I see your point.  I thought since i is not changed in the parallel region that it would not matter if it was declared private or shared but I see now that it might effect optimization.

Comment: One can use `-O3 -fdump-tree-all` and examine the `.c.126t.final_cleanup` file and see how different the code is. In the serial version `i` is eliminated altogether while in the shared version `i` is reloaded every time.

Comment: @Hristo N - 960, C - 6680000. For this case, sequential time is 16s and OpenMP with 1 thread is 19s. Therefore the overhead is about 20%. I'd like to know whether this is normal. Thanks

Comment: Add the `firstprivate(i,C)` clause and see how it changes the timings.

Comment: @warunapww, how much did `firstprivate(i,C)` improve the performance?